# How to throw custom exceptions using functions based on custom exception construct in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I Have a custom `Exception` Construct and I want to throw custom exception using a function instead of using `throw new ExceptionName("msg")`. 
I read [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions) and I was successful to implement it using `VB` but not `C#`.

This is my custom Construct:

```
[Serializable()]
    public class ArtCoreExceptions : Exception
    {
        public ArtCoreExceptions()
        {
        }

        public ArtCoreExceptions(string message)
        : base(message)
        {
        }

        public ArtCoreExceptions(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
        {

        }
        protected ArtCoreExceptions(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
       System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        { }
    }
```

I tried to do define a function like:

```
UploadFailureException ArtCoreExceptions()
    {
        string description = "My NewFileIOException Description";

        return new ArtCoreExceptions(description);
    }
```

but the compiler gives me a missing reference error for "UploadFailureException "

**Background**

In `VB` I used to do the following:

```
Public Class ArtCoreExceptions 
        Inherits Exception
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
        Public Sub New(message As String)
            MyBase.New(message)
        End Sub
        Public Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
            MyBase.New(message, inner)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, context _
     As StreamingContext)
            MyBase.New(info, context)
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Function UploadFailureException() As ArtCoreExceptions 
        Dim description As String = "File could not be uploaded"
        Return New ARTSQLExceptions(description)
    End Function
```

And I used to `throw UploadFailureException` as an exception, How can I do the same in `C#`

Comment: Have you considered creating a UploadFailureException class derived from ArtCoreExceptions _"public class UploadFailureException : ArtCoreExceptions { public UploadFailureException() : base("File could not be uploaded") {} }"_ - you maybe able to handle specific exceptions better than having a generic exception & the top of the stack trace will always refer to the point of the exception rather than a following function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up here. `UploadFailureException`  is name of method( or functions whatever you like to call) while `ArtCoreExceptions`  is class name.

```
ArtCoreExceptions UploadFailureException ()
    {
        string description = "My NewFileIOException Description";

        return new ArtCoreExceptions(description);
    }
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere, @Niladri .... I get this error `A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods`

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar You have to put this method into a class of cours, as in your VB-code where the method belongs to `ArtCoreExceptions`-class

Comment: @AhmadAbuMaizar you have to put this method in a class and you should also have a `ArtCoreExceptions` class

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to *return* `ArtCoreExceptions`. The return-value within a method-signature comes *before* it´s name, not *after* it.

```
ReturnType MethodName(params) { ... }
```

In contrast to VB where you write the name of the function *before*  it´s return-type:

```
Function MethodName() As ReturnType
```

So use `ArtCoreExceptions UploadFailureException ()` { ... } instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Public Function UploadFailureException() As ArtCoreExceptions 
        Dim description As String = "File could not be uploaded"
        Return New ARTSQLExceptions(description)
    End Function
```

This above code creates a function UploadFailureException() whose return type is an object of type ArtCoreExceptions . You can do the same in C# as below

```
public ArtCoreExceptions UploadFailureException()
    {
        string description = "My NewFileIOException Description";

        return new ArtCoreExceptions(description);
    }
```

which returns an instance of class `ArtCoreExceptions` derived from `System.Exception.`